# Message is not uploading when button is clicked

Tags: android, twitter

Button event is here :

```
  btnUpdateStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Call update status function
                // Get the status from EditText
                String status = txtUpdate.getText().toString();

                // Check for blank text
                if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
                    // update status
                    new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
                } else {
                    // EditText is empty
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter status message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
```

here is update dmethod
class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask {

```
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Places JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
        String status = args[0];
        try {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

            // Access Token 
            String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
            // Access Token Secret
            String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

            // Update status
            twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);
             Log.i(""+response, "value");
            Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // Error in updating status
            Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
     * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
     * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                // Clearing EditText field
                txtUpdate.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Here is the XML layout :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <!-- Twitter Login Button -->
     <Button android:id="@+id/btnLoginTwitter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login with Twitter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>

    <!-- user name label -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lblUserName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"/>

    <!-- label update status -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lblUpdate"
        android:text="Update Status"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <!-- Tweet EditText -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/txtUpdateStatus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <!-- Tweet Button -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnUpdateStatus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tweet"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <!-- Twitter Logout button -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogoutTwitter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Logout from Twitter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:visibility="visible"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

I am using twitter SDK and twiiter 4jcore library for sending message and login with twitter. I am getting successful login but when I am writing any message for update on twitter, my message is not showing on my twitter account. What I am doing wrong? I followed this tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/) but my message is not showing.

Comment: Means you couldn't see your tweets on Twitter???

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes sir..,i am not getting any message which i am writing from my device or from my emiulator.

Comment: Check your code for post tweets to Twitter

Comment: @PiyushGupta sir i checked all thing.,but not getting any solution

Comment: Post your send tweets code

Comment: You should put Log snippets into the different branches of your code so that you can identify the problem. If you put code in your onClickListener and you don't see any log output then you know there's an issue with your click listener. Otherwise like Piyush hints, it may be an issue with your tweet sending code.

Comment: @PiyushGupta sir i am getting this twitter exception.....403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
message - Your credentials do not allow access to this resource.
code - 220

Comment: which twitter jar file u r using

Comment: @PiyushGupta i am using this file twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar

Comment: Are you sending same message on twitter?

Comment: @PiyushGupta sending same message means???

Comment: Means like message "Hi". So every time you are sending "Hi" message??

Comment: @PiyushGupta no sir..,i am sending diffrent2 messages

Comment: Try to change if (statuslength() > 0 || !status.isEmpty()) {
                    // update status
                    new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
                }

Comment: @PiyushGupta ok sir i try

Comment: @PiyushGupta sir..,thats not working..:(

Comment: @PiyushGupta sir i have added my updated class in code..

Comment: @rajshree you are catching twitter exception in doinBackground method and in the post execute you are not checking status and simply shows success message. This will show success even in case of failed attempts.

Comment: @gvmani yes i have understood that execption.,and i am finding solution for that but what sholid i do,please help me and suggest me..

Comment: @rajshree you mentioned that you are getting twitterexception due to the messaging limit of your account, is it still the case or have you encountered any new issues? Either way you need to change how you show the message in post execute as you have not taken care of error condition.

Comment: Follow this link [Demo twitter post with oath](https://github.com/learnNcode/DemoTwitterImagePost). Check the tutorials post to twitter method. If your still facing issues let me know.